# How make expandable ListView with RadioListTiles?

Tags: dart, flutter, radio-group

I changed an example [ExpansionTile](https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample/), added some Radios. But they are not working right. I would like to have a choice of not more than one. 
[Screenshot gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6bhl.gif)
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpansionTileSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          new EntryItem(data[index]),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// One entry in the multilevel list displayed by this app.
class Entry {
  Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);

  final String title;
  final List<Entry> children;
}

// The entire multilevel list displayed by this app.
final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry(
    'Chapter A',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry(
        'Section A0',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item A0.1'),
          new Entry('Item A0.2'),
          new Entry('Item A0.3'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Section A1'),
      new Entry('Section A2'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter B',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section B0'),
      new Entry('Section B1'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter C',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section C0'),
      new Entry('Section C1'),
      new Entry(
        'Section C2',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item C2.0'),
          new Entry('Item C2.1'),
          new Entry('Item C2.2'),
          new Entry('Item C2.3'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class EntryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);
  final Entry entry;

  @override
  EntryItemState createState() {
    return new EntryItemState(entry);
  }
}

class EntryItemState extends State<EntryItem> {
  Entry entry;
  EntryItemState(Entry entry){
    this.entry = entry;
  }
  int radioValue = 0;

  void handleRadioValueChanged(int value) {
    setState(() {
      radioValue = value;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(root.title),
              new Radio(
                  key: new Key(root.title),
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: radioValue,
                  onChanged: handleRadioValueChanged)
            ],
          )
      );
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(widget.entry);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new ExpansionTileSample());
}
```

Please, show how to fix the code so that in each group there is no more than one value. I can not find a solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to pick the options, one by one I modified your code as follows.

```
class ExpansionTileSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          new EntryItem(data[index]),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// One entry in the multilevel list displayed by this app.
class Entry {
  Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);

  final String title;
  int radioValue = 0;
  final List<Entry> children;
}

// The entire multilevel list displayed by this app.
final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry(
    'Chapter A',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry(
        'Section A0',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item A0.1'),
          new Entry('Item A0.2'),
          new Entry('Item A0.3'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Section A1'),
      new Entry('Section A2'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter B',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section B0'),
      new Entry('Section B1'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter C',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section C0'),
      new Entry('Section C1'),
      new Entry(
        'Section C2',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item C2.0'),
          new Entry('Item C2.1'),
          new Entry('Item C2.2'),
          new Entry('Item C2.3'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class EntryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);
  final Entry entry;

  @override
  EntryItemState createState() {
    return new EntryItemState(entry);
  }
}

class EntryItemState extends State<EntryItem> {
  Entry entry;
  EntryItemState(Entry entry){
    this.entry = entry;
  }

  void handleRadioValueChanged(int value, Entry root) {
    setState(() {
      root.radioValue = value;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      print("title: ${root.title} , radioValue: ${root.radioValue}");
      return new ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(root.title),
              new Radio(
                  key: new Key(root.title),
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: root.radioValue,
                  onChanged: (value) => handleRadioValueChanged(value, root))
            ],
          )
      );
    }
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(widget.entry);
  }
}
```

The changes what I did is to assign different `radioValue` to each Entry and update only the related `radioValue` in `Entry`.

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

If you would like to be able to pick only one option, then you are expected to create children's of the radio buttons. You may check the below method for that.

```
Widget buildRadio() {
    return new Align(
      alignment: const Alignment(0.0, -0.2),
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Radio<int>(
                value: 0,
                groupValue: radioValue,
                onChanged: handleRadioValueChanged
              ),
              new Radio<int>(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: radioValue,
                onChanged: handleRadioValueChanged
              ),
              new Radio<int>(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: radioValue,
                onChanged: handleRadioValueChanged
              )
            ]
          ),
          // Disabled radio buttons
          new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const <Widget>[
              const Radio<int>(
                value: 0,
                groupValue: 0,
                onChanged: null
              ),
              const Radio<int>(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: 0,
                onChanged: null
              ),
              const Radio<int>(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: 0,
                onChanged: null
              )
            ]
          )
        ]
      )
    );   }
```